# Plot of function-generated lists: Why does this workaround not work?

Tags: plotting, evaluation

My problem is a classic one: I want to plot a function-generated list, and there's no way to pre-evaluate (because the actual function includes `NMinimize` and thus cannot be calculated on symbolic values). I use the following replacement for the actual function:

```
f[x_?NumericQ]:={x,x^2}
```

Now doing

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated->True]
```

will still generate only one colour, as evaluation with a symbolic value will not generate a list. So I thought I could bypass this by just saving the result in a temporary variable and creating a wrapper function to read that out again (after all, unlike Mathematica, I *do* know the shape of the generated list):

```
Module[{fwrap1,fwrap2,tmp},
  fwrap1[x_?NumericQ] := (tmp = f[x])[[1]];
  fwrap2[x_?NumericQ] := tmp[[2]];
  Plot[{fwrap1[x], fwrap2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]]
```

I expected this to work as follows:

- First, `fwrap1` is called, which obtains the complete list from `f`, stores it in `tmp` and returns the first item.
- Then, `fwrap2` is called, which just reads the second value which `fwrap1` stored in `tmp`.

However while this indeed gives two colours as expected, the second function is replaced with a constant value (the one at maximal x).

By having `fwrap2` increment a counter, I can verify that it is called 53 times, and by recording the minimal and maximal x, I can verify that it is indeed called on the complete interval (well, at least at both end points). Moreover, adding lines of the form

```
Print[{fwrap1[0.5],fwrap2[0.5]}];
```

inside the module (with different values each time) gives the expected output.

So why does this code not work?

Comment: You assumed that, for each value of `x`, `fwrap1` is called, then `fwrap2`. However, from the behavior you observe I suspect that `Plot` calculates all values for `fwrap1` first, repeatedly rewriting the value of `tmp` and discarding the intermediate values you wanted to save; only afterwards does it move on to `fwrap2`. This would seem to make sense with the fact that only the value of `tmp` corresponding to one of the boundaries of the $x$ range is retained.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I now tested the call order, and indeed, after an initial single call to each, there follows a row of calls only to `fwrap1`, and then another row of calls only to `fwrap2`. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped. I've converted to an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm turning my previous comment into an answer. In your case, you assumed that, for each value of $x$, `fwrap1` is called, then `fwrap2`.

However, from the behavior you observe I suspect that `Plot` calculates all values for `fwrap1` first, repeatedly rewriting the value of `tmp` and discarding the intermediate values you wanted to save; only afterwards does it move on to `fwrap2`.

This would seem to make sense with the fact that only the value of `tmp` corresponding to one of the boundaries of the $x$ range is retained.

Answer (score 0):

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := {x, x^2}
```

These three expressions all produce the same output.  [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html) is used in each case to suppress the message "Part::partw: "Part 2 of f[x] does not exist."

```
Module[{fwrap1, fwrap2, tmp},
  fwrap1[x_] := (tmp = f[x])[[1]];
  fwrap2[x_] := tmp[[2]];
  Plot[{fwrap1[x], fwrap2[x]}, {x, 0, 1},
   Evaluated -> True,
   PlotLegends -> {x, x^2}]] //
 Quiet

Module[{fwrap1, fwrap2, tmp},
  fwrap1[x_] = (tmp = f[x])[[1]];
  fwrap2[x_] = tmp[[2]];
  Plot[{fwrap1[x], fwrap2[x]}, {x, 0, 1},
   PlotLegends -> {x, x^2}]] //
 Quiet

Module[{tmp},
  Plot[
   {(tmp = f[x])[[1]], tmp[[2]]},
   {x, 0, 1},
   Evaluated -> True,
   PlotLegends -> {x, x^2}]] //
 Quiet
```

[image]

EDIT:

Looking at the number of times at `f[x]` is evaluated

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := (n++; {x, x^2})

n = 0;
Module[{fwrap1, fwrap2, tmp}, fwrap1[x_] := (tmp = f[x])[[1]];
  fwrap2[x_] := tmp[[2]];
  Plot[{fwrap1[x], fwrap2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> {x, x^2}]] // Quiet; n

(*  159  *)

n = 0;
Module[{fwrap1, fwrap2, tmp}, fwrap1[x_] = (tmp = f[x])[[1]];
   fwrap2[x_] = tmp[[2]];
   Plot[{fwrap1[x], fwrap2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {x, x^2}]] // 
  Quiet;
n

(*  159  *)

n = 0;
Module[{tmp}, 
   Plot[{(tmp = f[x])[[1]], tmp[[2]]}, {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True, 
    PlotLegends -> {x, x^2}]] // Quiet;
n

(*  159  *)

n = 0; Plot[{f[x][[1]], f[x][[2]]}, {x, 0, 1}];
n

(*  238  *)
```

Comment: But all those do the equivalent of `Plot[f[x][[1]], f[x][[2]],{x,0,1}]`. That is, the function is evaluated twice (this can easily be verified by incrementing a counter in the function; with my version, there are 78 calls, with any of yours, there are 158). The whole point of that construction is that this extra call is avoided (as the calls of the actual function are expensive).

Comment: @celtschk - See edit with counters. The code that you posted as equivalent to mine (after your syntax is corrected) executes `f`` 238 times vice 159; so they are not equivalent. I do not know what other code to which you are comparing.

Comment: I'm comparing with the code I posted in my question (the one that gave the wrong curves). That code makes only 78 calls to `f` (tested on Mathematica 8.0). However I defined the function for counting as `f[x_?NumericQ] := {count++; x, x^2}`.

Comment: @celtschk - it makes no sense to me to compare performance of working code against non-working code. The fact that the curve is wrong impacts the adaptive algorithm that determines the number of points used for drawing the curve. Consequently, you can only reasonably compare code that produces the same curves.